# Trying to add a managed object property gives a compile error?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I have a Swift project which has Core Data enabled. I check `AppDelegate` and I see the extra functions. I made a mistake and renamed the `xcdatamodeld` file and also renamed it in `AppDelegate.swift`

In my main viewcontroller, I added `import CoreData`

and I tried to define the property:

```
class ScannerViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, AVCaptureMetadataOutputObjectsDelegate {

let moContext = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext
```

But when I test I immediately get a compile error:

compile error:

> 0x1002a4a78 <+40>:  bl     0x1002f1910               ; function signature specialization  of Swift.(_fatalErrorMessage (Swift.StaticString, Swift.StaticString, Swift.StaticString, Swift.UInt) -> ()).(closure #2)
>   ->  0x1002a4a7c <+44>:  brk    #0x1
>       0x1002a4a80 <+48

If I uncomment `let moContext` the app compiles without any error.

[EDIT] i also see

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

does this mean my managed object context is nil??

[EDIT 2]
I think i have found the cause: I have renamed the .xcdatamodeld and also did edit in AppDelegate.swift but i think that isn't the correct way. So how can i rename the .xcdatamodeld file without a runtime error??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25394749/unexpectedly-found-nil-while-unwrapping-an-optional-value)

Comment: This is not a compile error, it's a runtime one

Comment: I think i have found the cause: see my edit